# AngularJS: How to format ISO8601 date format?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and using ISO8601 datetime format as `yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ` as mentioned in their options section

In my controller, I do

```
transaction.date = $('.form_datetime input').val();
```

which sends the data to backend as (console.log)

```
created_on: "Wed, 08 May 2013 23:18:32 -0000"
```

and saves in database as

```
2013-05-08 16:18:32-07
```

In my template, I do

```
<td>{{ transaction.created_on | date:'medium'}}</td>
```

and I see the output on my HTML as

```
Wed, 08 May 2013 23:18:32 -0000
```

But as per the [Angular doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date), it should be for format `Oct 28, 2010 8:40:23 PM`

What is that I am missing?

Comment: I gave the example format from Angular Doc

Comment: Might want to make it consistent with a valid *expected* result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For now, I have created a filter

```
angular.module('customFilters', []).
  filter('dateInMillis', function() {
    return function(dateString) {
      return Date.parse(dateString);
    };
  });
```

added as dependency in `app.js` as

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  '$strap.directives', 'ngCookies', 'categoryServices', 'transactionServices',
  'customFilters'
]);
```

and in `HTML` used it as

```
<!-- added dateInMillis to pass to date to filter Angular way -->
<td>{{ transaction.created_on | dateInMillis | date: 'medium'}}</td>
```

and that presents date on `HTML` as

```
May 8, 2013 5:14:36 PM
```

If you know a better idea, please let me know

Comment: `return Date.parse(dateString);` how does it know the format?

Answer (score 51):

I don't understand why no one provided the simple answer of using the correct format in the filter?

```
{{item.date | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'}}
```

That will format as ISO-8601

Comment: It uses `4 digit (+sign) representation of the timezone offset`. This is slightly different with `moment().format();`

Answer (score 9):

In Brazil (and most of Europe, Australia, etc.), we use the default MySQL DATETIME on DB's:

```
"Y-m-d HH:ii:ss"
```

But use date() to display it like this:

```
"d/m/Y HH:ii:ss"
```

So in order to display that date in angular, "correctly", create a filter:

```
var app = angular.module(...

// Converts MySQL datetime into readable BR format
/*
    Converts 2013-10-18 18:47:15 into 1382122035000 so angular can format date 
    using brazilian standards
*/
app.filter('brDateFilter', function() {
    return function(dateSTR) {
        var o = dateSTR.replace(/-/g, "/"); // Replaces hyphens with slashes
        return Date.parse(o + " -0000"); // No TZ subtraction on this sample
    }
});
```

Then, on your angular app, just call the filter and format the value for display:

```
{{ item.datetime_value | brDateFilter | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" }}
```

That covers date format in Brazilian, UK, New Zealand, etc. date format for angular, just subtract the timezone correctly.

Comment: This was a huge help to format default MySQL dates. Works out of the box. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Beside all this, just you have change like this,

```
<td>{{ transaction.created_on | date:'medium'}}</td>
```

try to wirte it as

```
<td>{{ transaction.created_on | date:'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a'}}</td>
```