# How to extract the time from the ISO8601 standard date format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a date sting in the format as below:
2017-05-25T08:00:00.0000000+00:00

How to Extract the time in hh:ss format from the ISO format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451851/angularjs-how-to-format-iso8601-date-format

Comment: a starting point `isoDateString.split('T')[1]`

Comment: @ManasHemrajani - that's not related - this question is about extracting the time from an ISO string, that question is about creating an ISO string

Comment: `"DateString".match(/(\d+:\d+:\d+)+/)[0];`

Comment: no need for `g` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX `:D`

Answer (score 1):

As ISO8601 is strictly defined, a simple `substr` will do it

```js
console.log('2017-05-25T08:00:00.0000000+00:00'.substr(11,8));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with `.match()` method:

```js
var date = "2017-05-25T08:00:00.0000000+00:00";
console.log(date.match(/(\d+:\d+:\d+)+/)[0])
```